# PLSQL: Ora-600 on Create MV with group by statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving a really strange error which I could narrow down to the following:

```
Select_1:
    Select T1.article_id 
      from table_1 T1 
      left join (select article_id from Table_2@db_link inner_T2 ) T2 
        on T1.artile_Id = T2.article_id
     group by T1.article_id
```

Select_1 can be executed.

Create view as Select_1 can be executed.

Create MV as Select_1 gives ORA-00600, Arguments: [kkdlGetCkyName1], [575038], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

If I omit the group by part from Select_1 then also the MV executes. If I group by inner_t2 first then the MV executes also with the outer group by. Overall the other group by does not even do anything on the current dataset  - num_rows are equal with and without the outer group by.

Can anyone put some sense into this behavior?

Best, Peter

Comment: One GROUP BY too many. (Or two...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ORA-00600`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-00600/) is:

> The generic internal error number for Oracle program exceptions. It indicates that a process has encountered a low-level, unexpected condition.

To fix it you will probably need to talk to Oracle support (under your support contract) and they may issue you with a patch to fix the internal issue that is causing the problem.

---

However, the query does not use any data from `Table_2@db_link inner_T2` as the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses do not reference `t2` and `T2` is `OUTER JOIN`ed so has no effect if a matching row is not present.

You can rewrite it as:

```sql
SELECT article_id 
FROM   table_1
GROUP BY article_id
```

or:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT article_id 
FROM   table_1
```

Comment: Hi MTO, so basically no one needs to understand an ORA-600? (I know that my select statement is silly. I was only trying to make minimal what made sense with some extra data.) Best, Peter

Comment: @PeterFrey Oracle support can understand ORA-00600 errors (if they have the appropriate log files). Ordinary people cannot understand it because it relates to many different undocumented proprietary internal features of Oracle databases and it is simply Oracle's short-hand for "this shouldn't have gone wrong but something unexpected has gone wrong internally so contact us and provide us some logs and a [MRE] and we'll help you to sort it out (and if its a bug they'll issue you a patch)." If I could give you a solution, I would, but the solution to ORA-00600 is "talk to Oracle support".